# What are It's powers?

Tags: stephen-king, it

In *It*, by Stephen King, we find that It is a female entity, just like the Turtle, created by some higher power, eternal, ruler of the universe, and member of the macroverse.

It assumed a physical shape to come to Earth, where it feeds of meat tendered with fear. We know it can change its shape, read into people's minds, can control some people (those who are most insane), and control the weather (nearly destroying Maine a couple of times).

Is that all? This supreme entity can essentially control the Derry zone (its lair) and change shape? What is the extent of It's powers?

Comment: Eldritch abominations don't like reality in general, so being defined and written up on a stat sheet is right out.  They'll make you bleed bugs if you do.

Comment: Seeing as the genre were talking about here - *horror* - draws much of its effect from the *unknown*, I very much doubt that King, an experienced horror writer, gave an exposé on It's powers and limitations. I suppose I haven't checked, but it would be weird indeed.

Comment: This is a hard question to answer definitively like Radhil and Misha R have already made clear. I'll get around to giving this question a proper answer one day, but you've essentially summarized It's noteworthy powers yourself anyway.

Comment: @XeLa It is an acceptable answer to say that those are basically its powers

Answer (score 3):

From what I saw in both IT movies-his powers where:

ESP-reading minds-to learn your fears

Immortality-"Kill it", it takes another form and waits to strike later.

Matter Manipulation-creates various visual constructs capable of interacting with the real world, and can change form at will. This has LIMITS though-and would be a very different villain if there were no limits.

Teleportation-he moves around pretty quick, but doesn't seem to have super speed.

Multiple Projection-seems to be in several different places at once.

Dead Lights-the madness or instant death from seeing IT's true eyes.

It doesn't seem to us his real powers together effectively. This I believe is due to the Fear it tries to place in each victim. It tries to bring out the MOST fear possible out of someone before going for a kill. It doesn't seem to be omnipotent with his power use-and limits it to the person/people being targeted.

Comment: Wouldn't count the deadlights as a "power", more so  than just being Its "True Form." Everything else seems spot on, though.

Answer (score 2):

The entity dubbed "it" by the Losers was essentially an other dimensional, non-corporeal being which used a special type of magic called *Glamour* to put on the appearance of whatever it's prey's greatest fear was. It could peer into the mind of its victim and read this fear before taking its shape. This would give it the powers of:

- Telepathy, or some form of psionic ability
- Shape shifting, as in changing its own physical form.
- Illusion casting [it would often create things only one person would see]
- Some form of emotional manipulation [This was seen in how It's presence would bring out the *Worst* in people, even those not directly affected by it. Whether this is it "giving off" the bad vibes and people unconsciously reacting to it, or It *feeding* off the negativity is unclear.

As it has no "mortal" form, the creature is also extremely long lived, seeming to have come to earth in something like an asteroid eons ago. It also seems capable of producing *Actual* physical items, not just illusions, such as the knives and car it supplies to Henry Bowers. It also seems to be capable of limited emotional manipulation on a psychic level, amplifying negative feelings in people and communicating in their heads.

In the book, there was some ambiguous link between It and Derry, as not only did it's power seem limited to that space, but also because in the book, when the adult Losers returned to face it in the final confrontation, the weather in Derry reflected the cataclysmic battle; a *massive* tornado storm and flood seemed to rip the town itself apart.